# заполнение массива числами Фибоначчи

Tags: java, массивы, методы, числа-фибоначчи

Решал, казалось бы, простую задачу, даже погуглил потом правильный код... Но в консоль выводится массив заданной величины, который заполнен единицами. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      prMass(fibMass(20));

    }

    public static int[] fibMass(int x)
    {
        int m[]=new int[x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(m[i]<2)
                m[i]=1;
            else
                m[i]=m[i-1]+m[i-2];
        }

        return m;
    }
    public static void prMass(int[] x)
    {   int z=x.length;
        for(int i=0;i<z;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(x[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
    if(m[i]<2)
         m[i]=1;
    else
         m[i]=m[i-1]+m[i-2];
}
```

Вы для каждого элемента массива, если его значение меньше двух, задаете значение равное `1`. И переходите к следующему элементу.

Поскольку изначально массив инициализирован нулями, вполне ожидаемо, что вы получаете массив единиц.

Comment: стоило бы дописать что нужно сменить проверку элемента  на проверку индекса :-)

Comment: Спасибо,даже не пойму как это можно было не заметить..

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще одно решение:

```
     public class Fibonacci {
      public static int result=0;
      public static int count=0;
      public static int a=1, b=1;
      public static int GenerateFibonacci(int number) {
        while (count<=number){
          System.out.print(a+" ");
          b=b+a;
          a=b-a;
          count++;
        }
        return result;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenerateFibonacci(5);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
    if(i<2)
       m[i]=1;
    else
       m[i]=m[i-1]+m[i-2];
}
```

Comment: @Mihanik71, как ни странно, но _В опубликованном сообщении содержится решение вопроса_

Comment: @user217504 было бы хорошо если бы Вы указали в чём именно проблема

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использование stream:

```
    int count = 100;
    Stream
            .generate(new Supplier<BigDecimal>() {
                BigDecimal prevSecondNumber = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                BigDecimal prevFirstNumber = BigDecimal.ZERO;

                @Override
                public BigDecimal get() {
                    BigDecimal result = prevFirstNumber.add(prevSecondNumber);
                    if (Objects.equals(result, BigDecimal.ZERO)) result = BigDecimal.ONE;

                    prevSecondNumber = prevFirstNumber;
                    prevFirstNumber = result;

                    return result;
                }
            })
            .limit(count)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```